# Need help triggering a database error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using the CodeIgniter $db->insert function to preform an insert. But I am trying to figure out how to trigger an error with the query to see if the system logs the error message.

I have tried to misspell  the table name but that wouldn't work..it would just show an error message on the page.

Any ideas on how I can preform a fake error? Below is my code..

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
 public function newMsgTemplate($template_name, $body){


        try {

            $this->db->insert("message_template", ['template_name' => $template_name, 'body' => $body]);
            trigger_error("error");
        } catch (Exception $e){

            log_message("error", "There was an error when trying to preform the query ");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing the exception yourself.

```
public function newMsgTemplate($template_name, $body){
    try {
        $this->db->insert("message_template", ['template_name' => $template_name, 'body' => $body]);
        trigger_error("error");
        throw new MyException('foo!');
    } catch (Exception $e){

        log_message("error", "There was an error when trying to preform the query ");

    }
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)